# The onclick attribute is not responding in PUG

Tags: javascript, onclick, pug

```
 .lists
    .lists-flex.main-list
      ul#ingredientsList 
        each ingredient in ingredientsList 
          button#item(onclick="getString(#{ingredient.id})")=`${ingredient.name}`
 
    .lists-flex.substitute-display
      p= `${altInfo}`
```

When you click on a button, it should send the value of `ingredient.id` to the router module. The router module will then render the value of `altInfo` to the page. However, I can not figure out how to make the `onclick` attribute to respond at all, whether if it's writing the function in `script` in PUG or in the router module.

````js
app.post("/home", 
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      let list = await res.locals.store.displayAll();
      let string = 'This test has failed';

      function getString() {
        string = document.getElementById("item");
        console.log(string.innerHTML);
      }

      console.log(string)

      res.render("lists", {
        ingredientsList: list,
        altInfo: string,
        grabString
      })
    } catch(error) {
      next(error)
    }```
````

Comment: You can't access server-side javascript from the slient. Your function have to be included in the html

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there another attribute you can recommend that I can use to access the server side or should I forgo this route?